# SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault in .NET Class Library containing a form

Tags: vb.net, class, vb6

I have a .net class library with a com class that calls a form.
I want to to `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)` to ensure the form fonts look nice.

If I run the command in the class constructor I get the following error:
`SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.`

Where can/should I run this?  Surely there is no earlier place than sub New!

Thank in advance

Jon

Edit1: To clarify, I get this error when initiating the class from a .net test harness, if I call it from a VB6 app then I simply get "Automation Error"

Edit2: Is the answer that I cannot use `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` in a com class when calling from a vb6 app??  Maybe it's the "parent" app that needs to call this method and as such a vb6 app cannot?

***Edit3: Maybe I am asking this question in the wrong way! - Maybe the question is: how can I make the fonts look nice in a .net class library form called from a vb6 app?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible workaround would be to set the property manually on all buttons and labels in the form constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DisableCompatibleTextRendering(this);
}

private static void DisableCompatibleTextRendering(Control c)
{
    var button = (c as ButtonBase);
    var label = (c as Label);

    if (button != null)
    {
        button.UseCompatibleTextRendering = false;
    }

    if (label != null)
    {
        label.UseCompatibleTextRendering = false;
    }

    foreach (var child in c.Controls.Cast<Control>())
    {
        DisableCompatibleTextRendering(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's an old question, but I've the same problem and I need this for my textboxes. Is there a way to do this for a textbox? thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Place this inside the application startup code before the first window is created. Under C# this would be the *main* routine that then creates the initial window.

Comment: Because this is a class which has a function calling the form, then I was under the impression that sub New is the "application startup code"?